# Read text coordinate inside an image

Tags: .net, image, width, coordinate

I have an image. It contains some text. I want to read the coordinates of this text within that image. It should return width , X/Y Attributes.

What is the best way to achieve this .Net?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using the Tessnet2 library, it solves my purpose.

Comment: can you link to the library and explain what it does - is it an OCR library, or does it add metadata to the image? Downvoting because Klaudiusz bryjamus suggested this first and explained it more.

Answer (score 1):

I used [hOcr2Pdf](http://hocrtopdf.codeplex.com/) library and [Google Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) to achive something similar. HOCR format describe OCR'ed text using HTML so you have all lines/words/letters bounds.

Comment: Is it possible to pass words as input and get results? For e.g. if any image has 5 words, I would want coordinates of only 2 words, so is it achievable?

Comment: I think yes but you have to code by yourself. hOcr is HTML so you need to use regular expression or something else to search by lines/words/letters. [Here is hOcr format specification](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QQnIQtvdAC_8n92-LhwPcjtAUFwBlzE8EWnKAxlgVf0/preview)